# resolve checking one box and unchecking the other

Tags: android, xml, checkbox

I am trying to have my two checkboxes have separate values, when one is checked the other is unchecked. I am able to accomplish this using:

```
 final CheckBox checkYes = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.visual_yes);
        final CheckBox checkNo = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.visual_no);

        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checker = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (checkYes.isChecked() ) {

                    checkNo.setChecked(false);
//                    finish();
                }
                else if (checkNo.isChecked()) {
                    checkYes.setChecked(false);

//                    finish();
                }
                savePrefs("checkYesVisual", checkYes.isChecked());
                savePrefs("checkNoVisual",checkNo.isChecked());
            }
        };
        checkYes.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checker);
        checkNo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checker);
    }
```

but my problem is that the first button that I press is the only one that works how it should. For example, if I press yes first and then press no after it doesn't switch. But if I press no and then yes the check switches (as I want it to).

I believe my problem is with setting the checkNo textbox to false when yes is clicked and that value just saving until the yes box is unchecked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you @Ismael I didn't know radio buttons existed, got it working! If you write it as an answer I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain this behaviour using radio button groups

Answer (score 2):

As Ismael said, the behavior you are looking for is a Radio group with radio buttons. Only one can be checked and it automatically unchecks the others.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pirates"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ninjas"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Please do not check it as the answer if it fits your needs. Ask Ismael to write his comment as an answer because he diserves all the credit.